# Having issue in get_timeline() function of rtweet package

Tags: get, data-analysis, timeline, rtweet

I am new to learning twitter data analysis in R. I am trying to analyse some data using rtweet package. For some reason, 
there is an error in the function get_timeline().

```
cnn <- get_timeline("cnn", n = 3200)
    Error in get_timeline_(user = "cnn", n = 3200, home = FALSE, max_id = NULL,  : 
      could not find function "isFALSE"
```

The other functions such as **search_tweets, get_followers, get_friends,** etc. are working fine.

Comment: You got this error by exactly doing what? You need to present more details

Comment: I installed rtweet package. I then followed steps to get Twitter Authroization. And was going through a simple tutorial, trying out basic functions such as search_tweets(), get_followers(), etc., but for some reason get_timeline() returns this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue of compatibility between R version and package version.
I had the same issue today using get_timeline function from rtweet. I have R version 3.4.4 and rtweet version 0.7.

Solved the issue by downgraded rtweet package version to 0.6 using devtools

```
library(devtools)
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rtweet/rtweet_0.6.9.tar.gz")
```

I then restarted R session and the error was gone.

Comment: Hi, I was facing trouble installing devtools package in my version of R (3.3.3).  Ended up installing twitteR package instead. Can access timelines through it. But yes couldn't solve the original issue. Thanks for your help.